# Express customs engine view replace content error

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to replace content while "fs.readFile" is loaded.

Here is my code

```
app.engine('html', function (filePath, options, callback) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, content) {
    if (err) return callback(err)

      let rendered = content.toString();
      let regStr = '';
      let reg;

      for(let name in options) {
        regStr = '#(' + name + ')#';
        reg = new RegExp(regStr, 'g');

        rendered = rendered.replace(reg, options[name]);

      }


      return callback(null, rendered)
  });

});
```

And I reload the page in browser I got error message.

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
    at String.replace (native)
    at D:\docker_root\ifttt\app.js:57:29
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:446:3)
```

If I changed this line

```
rendered = rendered.replace(reg, options[name]);
```

to

```
rendered = rendered.replace(reg, 'other string will be fine');
```

It will be ok.

I don't know what's the problem with this code?
Why it can't replace loop value.

Comment: I found where problems are. Because express "options" will pass  "_locals","cache" those parameters are not my define so I always got error.